# problem with my code, using tbl_regression from gtsummary

Tags: r, datatables, model, gtsummary

I'm trying to summary model results in a table using the gtsummary package, and have some issues.

tried other version of rstudio and still the same problem.I need to make 32 tables so I think its the best option for me.
Thank you for any help.

this is my code (with different variations)

```
reccurent<-glm(reccurent_hosp~sex1+age+jew_dich+education_dich+north+south+jerusalem
                      +affective_schizoaffective+schizophrenia_psychotic
                      +other 
                      +heatwave_dich
                      +delta_temp+
                        +NOXF+SO2F+
                        O3_R15_mean+
                        PM10_R15_mean+RH,family=binomial, data=datar)


t1 <-tbl_regression(reccurent, exponentiate = TRUE)
```

also tried this `gtsummary::tbl_regression(model, exponentiate = TRUE)`

I got this errors:

> Error in tbl_regression(reccurent, exponentiate = TRUE) :
> could not find function "tbl_regression"

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
> there is no package called ‘stringi’

also had this issue:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gtsummary’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> there is no package called ‘stringi’

Comment: Try `install.packages("stringi")` and make sure `library(stringi)` runs without error first. Then try your code again.